# How can I get Postgres to generate partitions based on a field?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with three fields & composite primary key:

- SensorID, primary
- Timestamp, primary
- Value

I want Postgres to partition on SensorID. I do not know ahead of time what the SensorIDs will be. Postgres will need to generate new partitions as new SensorIDs arrive.

Questions:

- Should I be using a hash or list based partition?
- Is it possible to
  achieve this behaviour without using triggers?

Comment: The sensor id is an integer?  If so, hash seems to make sense and it would not require a trigger.

Comment: @Hambone SensorId would be a varchar string. Does that still apply?

Comment: I thought the hash partition worked off of a modulus, in which case it would imply numeric values.  Maybe there are other options -- to be honest, I've never used it.  I use partitions all the time, but almost always on range/date or occasionally list values.  I'm sure you can do some conversions (last character of varchar, converted to numeric, then modulus), but that seems simply awful.